# Copy png error with exit code 5

Tags: ios, xcode, perl

I tried to run a project in **Xcode 7.3.1** and got the following

**Error :**

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/libperl.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/bin/perl5.18
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/copypng failed with exit code 5
```

Why is that dyld library is not getting loaded?
How can I be able to sort this out? i have tried checking build phases and there are no images that are red in colour.

Comment: Try Clean then Build command

Comment: check library for your target at General->Linked Frameworks and Libraries it mast be in list

Comment: tried cleaning then tried building..got the same error

Answer (score 2):

You could try reinstalling Perl

```
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ranguard/installing-perl/master/scripts/install_perl_on_osx.sh | bash
```

Comment: tried reinstalling perl but still im having the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

You simply have problems starting system perl.

To restore library `/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/libperl.dylib` see this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116611/how-can-i-get-back-a-system-file-after-deleting-it-from-my-mac

Comment: As far as I know, perl is shipped with OS, not with Xcode

Comment: Checked and it seems that I may be wrong in the previous comment. Xcode Command Line Tools should contain perl so try to reinstall them, for example, running `xcode-select --install`

Comment: xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates